# Settings different values for appsettings.json foreach pod

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have  an application running on AKS with multiple pods. Each pod initiates a subscription to SErvice Bub topic subscription. However, each pod must subscribe to different subscription ID which is configured in appsettings.json

Does anyone know how to customize appsettings.json so that each pod gets a different version?

Comment: The replicas of a Deployment are _identical_, aside from a couple of specific details.  The Pod's host name will be the unique Pod name; could you maybe use this name?  You'd have to do something in your container startup to set up the JSON file using this.

Comment: If the names were predictable, I could code it so that pod-1 subscribed to subscription-1, pod-2 to subscription-2, but because names are dynamic I cannot do that...

Comment: If predictable names are a requirement, that's one of the things a StatefulSet gives you.

Comment: Can you try using configmap with the different versions of appsettings.json and then mount the configmap to each pod. The pod will then use the appsettings.json file from the configmap. For example kubectl create configmap appsettings --from-file=appsettings.json and 
kubectl create configmap appsettings2 --from-file=appsettings2.json and then mount the appsettings configmap to the /etc/appsettings directory in each pod